# Ubuntu Studio 19.04 laptop won't wake up from suspend

Tags: drivers, suspend, 19.04, ubuntu-studio

Like the title says: the laptop can't be awakened from "suspend" by any means I can figure out. The backlight comes on, the hard-disk light flickers a few time, but nothing happens without a hard reset. Tried plugging an HDMI cable in to see if I could see anything else; no dice.

The device is a brand-new HP 14cm-0111au.

lspci -vnn | grep VGA

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics] [1002:98e4] (rev e2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller]
```

uname -a

```
Linux Rabia 5.0.0-25-lowlatency #26-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Aug 1 13:08:53 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of cat /sys/kernel/debug/suspend_stats (and this seems very weird):

```
success: 0
fail: 0
failed_freeze: 0
failed_prepare: 0
failed_suspend: 0
failed_suspend_late: 0
failed_suspend_noirq: 0
failed_resume: 0
failed_resume_early: 0
failed_resume_noirq: 0
failures:
  last_failed_dev:  

  last_failed_errno:    0
            0
  last_failed_step:
```

On the basis of the advice given at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend, I ran pm_tracing, and here's the "Magic number" part of dmesg output:

```
[    1.377183]   Magic number: 0:66:273
[    1.377184]   hash matches drivers/base/power/main.c:1012
[    1.377197] usb usb1-port1: hash matches
[    1.377227] tty tty10: hash matches
[    1.377235] net lo: hash matches
```

I have no idea where to go from here. I went through the "Debugging Information" at the above link and have the 7 other pm_trace outputs in full, as well as the Xorg logs; I don't know how to attach them to this post, though.

Comment: Seems to be a bug with linux-kernel-amdgpu-binaries, have confirmed a report here: https://github.com/M-Bab/linux-kernel-amdgpu-binaries/issues/81

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it's a recognized bug in the AMDGPU open source graphics driver (see https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=110258). The fix is available as a patch here: https://cgit.freedesktop.org/drm/drm/commit/?h=drm-fixes&id=72cda9bb5e219aea0f2f62f56ae05198c59022a7

I needed to recompile my kernel (something I'd never done before and took a long time - for other newbies this guide is quite helpful https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) but this solved the issue and the computer now wakes up from suspend. Hopefully this fix will be included in future Ubuntu kernels.